# Обновление модели автокодировщика для обнаружения аномалий в потоке данных

Tags: нейронные-сети, анализ-данных

Использую нейросеть autoencoder для потока данных, а именно временных рядов которые поступают с течением времени. Обучаю сеть на данных за неделю, потом при помощи обученной модели обнаруживаю аномалии за день. Проблема в том что из за сезонности и трендов необходимо обновлять модель. Есть множество статьей и реализаций на гитбах про [использование автокодировщика для потока данных](https://github.com/binli826/LSTM-Autoencoders/blob/master/Thesis.pdf). По большому счету в этих работах описывается про то когда модель должна понять что ей нужно обновиться, но у меня это четко известно (она обнавляется каждый день и тренируется на данных за прошлую неделю). Непонятно как мне избежать аномальности в данных для обучения сети т.к. для ее корректной работы необходимы только нормальные данные - в моем случае те данные которые приходят за неделю должны быть без аномалий

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то смысл автоэнкодеров в том, что они должны нормально обучаться и на данных с аномалиями. За счёт того, что модель автоэнкодера делается специально упрощённой, она не может "переобучиться" и хорошо умеет обобщать и предсказывать только типовые данные, а аномалии, которых по определению мало, она учит плохо. Поэтому выходной сигнал автоэнкодера на аномалиях сильно отличается от входного сигнала и таким образом мы их и выявляем с помощью автоэнкодера.

Так что избегать аномальных данных при обучении автоэнкодера не нужно, но нужно грамотно подобрать параметры нейросети автоэнкодера, чтобы получить получше качество обнаружения (меньше ошибок как первого, так и второго рода). И да, со временем выборка может смещаться, поэтому надо периодически заново учить автоэнкодер, но выкидывать при этом аномалии вовсе не нужно, можно брать данные как есть.